# MySQL connector and server compatibility (VERSION.server file)

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, mariadb

I am building working on a simple mysql client based on [mysql-connector-c-6.1.3](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-src.tar.gz'). All works well, however I am seeing this warning:

```
Warning: MySQL client build with 5.7.4-m14 but loading MySQL 6.1.3
```

Looking through the source I found that mysql-connector-c has both a `VERSION` and `VERSION.server` file, defining two different versions, causing my client to warn about a potential incompatibility.

I don't understand the meaning of `VERSION.server` as this is a client library. I don't even have a server running at this point. Also I was under the impression that mysql only connects over the network, hence client and server version don't have to match exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source `mysql_version.cmake`:

```
GET_MYSQL_VERSION(VERSION.server)
SET(SERVER_VERSION ${VERSION})
SET(SERVER_VERSION_ID ${MYSQL_VERSION_ID})

# Get Connector/C version and other interesting variables
GET_MYSQL_VERSION()

MESSAGE(STATUS "LibMySQL ${VERSION}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Built from MySQL ${SERVER_VERSION} sources")
```

Apparently some server side code is included in the client (sounds reasonable), and `VERSION.server` merely contains the version number of that code.

It's strange though that somehow conflicting versions (that would trigger your warning) are distributed in a single source package.  Note I can't find that warning in this source package, perhaps you're building/linking/running something else?